# UITableView fixed section with dynamic size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to implement something like this:

[image]

I have a UITableView with 1. "static" section, the total number of sections in the tableView can vary. I always want the first section (white area) to be visible to the user, the remaining sections should scroll underneath the first section. I have tried to implement this with two UITableViews, but since the (white area) can vary in size, I can't set a definite frame. I am using Storyboards with autolayout. At the moment the best solution I have come up with is the two UITableViews, but I need to find a way that I can resize the two tableViews according to the content of the white area and according to each other. The white area, one of the tableViews is containing a section with two rows, the first row is containing text that can vary in length and therefore needs dynamic resizing. 
Any Idea how I can tackle this? Can I change the NSLayoutConstraints dynamically somehow?

Comment: You don't need two tableviews. Use a plain view for the static content and use a table view for the lower part. And you will need to write code to adjust both frames based on the size of the static content.

Comment: @rmaddy - An alternative way would be to have a view with the "fixed variable" stuff overlaying the top of the table view, and then define a dummy cell in the table view as tall as the overlaying view is.  This would eliminate the need to repeatedly resize the table view (which may or may not be a problem in some cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correct, your first UIView rectangle if fixed, bottom table is scrollable.

To implement this, you should create typical UIViewController, add UIView and UITableView (programmatically or through an outlets). You should manage each view (tableView and UIView) separately.